# How to display List<string> in html select control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have to bind the List in html select upon drag drop of the columns. The following is my function to get `list<string>`

```
    var oper;
   function FunctionScript() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Webtop.aspx/FunctionDropdown",
      data: {},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
          $("#ddOperators").empty();
          for (var i = 0, l = msg.d.length; i < l; i++) {
              $("#ddOperators").append("<option>" + msg.d[i] + "</option>");
              oper = msg.d;
              alert("Check Dropdown");
          }
          alert('Check Operator DropDown' + msg.d.length);
      }, 
      error: DisplayError 
  });


}
```

//The following function is used for dragdrop.

```
     function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      var uid = removeSpaces(draggable.attr('text'));
      FunctionScript();
      var colName = draggable.attr('title');
      $('#selectedColumns > tbody:last').append('<tr id="' + uid + '"><td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="chk" checked="checked" /></td><td><label>' + colName + '</label></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
    <td><select title="select table" id="ddOperators"/></td><td><input type="text" /></td>
     <td><div><input type="text" value="" size="20" name="txtForeColor"/><a id="pick2" name="pick2" href="#">Select Color</a></div></td><td></td></tr>');
          $("#selectedColumns").tableDnD({ onDragClass: "DragClass" });

    }
```

The id of select is `ddOperators`; Currently the select does not bind with the `list<strings>`.

Comment: For the first time, the list is get displayed but upon dragdrop the value in the select becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in your script.

replace

```
 var draggable = ui.draggable;
```

with

```
 var draggable = ui.draggable({helper:'clone'});
```